# ROS RQT Update Speed

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

In Subscribe Program or rostopic echo, Racing Wheel (Logitech G29) data is output well in real time.

However, RQT's Topic monitor seems to reflect the latest data slowly, does anyone know why?

Is it a simple RQT problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information such as a minimal way to reproduce your problem? Without more details there's not enough information to answer your question. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.